# Redirecting wordpress page to facebook page with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I need to redirect a page from my wordpress site to my facebook page. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this with htaccess? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
Redirect /pagename http://facebook.com/My-FB-Page
```